# How to concat several ts_vectors with new expression index from Npgsql 5?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, ef-core-5.0

We using concatenation of ts_vectors to support multiple languages in some columns. In old versions it was like that:

```
public class AddTsVectorIndexes : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            @"CREATE INDEX ""Name_TsVector"" ON ""SomeTable"" USING GIN
(((to_tsvector('russian', ""Name"") || to_tsvector('english', ""Name"")) || to_tsvector('simple', ""Name"")));");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"DROP INDEX ""Name_TsVector"";");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to concat ts_vectors with new sugar syntax of expression index added in Npgsql 5([docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/full-text-search.html#method-2-expression-index))?

Or maybe there is a way to create multilang ts_vector dictionary for parsers and just use it  as config for creation ts_vectors and ts_query?

Answer (score 0):

The sugar for creating full-text search indices is just that - sugar for the common usage. If you want anything else (like the above), you can very easily use [raw SQL in your migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#adding-raw-sql) instead, and specify whatever expression you want.